# How to find a particular string in excel file using Batch Scripting

Tags: batch-file, cmd, scripting

When i had to find a string in text file using batch script(.bat) in windows, below code worked:

```
findstr /s /i /n /p /c:"vijay" *.txt
```

but when i am trying to find string in excel file using below code its not working

```
findstr /s /i /n /p /c:"vijay" Book1.xlsx
```

Kindly suggest me a solution.

Comment: Xlsx is a proprietary file system, not a text file. What findstr reads is what you see when you open the file in a text editor. You'll have to use a language suited for interacting with Office products, like VBScript.

Comment: `xlsx` are `zip` archives, whith files and folders compressed inside. You will need to first decompress the archive to be able to search text inside.

Comment: Can u give me a reference example?